# Comments disappeared from Google Spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have been working on a shared Google Spreadsheet for months. All of a sudden, the comments have disappeared from the cells and now only appear in the discussion thread.

How can I get them back to their individual cells that they pertain to?